# Помогите проверить расстановку знаков препинания в примерах

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

1) Если между пятым и шестым подъездом, у дома №7, нам разбить садик, наверное это будет неплохо.

2) Нам, наверное, стоит разбить садик между пятым и шестым подъездом, у дома №7, так как это самый подходящий вариант.

3) Нам стоит разбить садик, скорее всего, между пятым и шестым подъездом, у дома №7.

4) А может у дома №7, между пятым и шестым подъездом,  попробовать  разбить садик.

Comment: Садиком принято называть детское учреждение. В других случаях подойдёт: палисад, сквер, детская площадка, игровая зона, зона озеленения, островок зелени. Так будет неплохо, наверное.

Answer (score 1):

1) Если между пятым и шестым подъездом, у дома №7, нам разбить садик, наверное это будет неплохо.

По Лопатину, вводное слово на границе двух предложений не обособляется, однако в других источниках вводное слово входит в двухместное союзное образование и обособляется: Если он уезжает, значит, ему так нравится. Кстати, в приведенном примере «наверное» явно относится ко второму предложению, поэтому нет смысла указывать на это отсутствием запятой.

2) Нам, наверное, стоит разбить садик между пятым и шестым подъездом, у дома №7, так как это самый подходящий вариант.

3) Нам стоит разбить садик - скорее всего, между пятым и шестым подъездом, у дома №7.

4) А может,  у дома №7, между пятым и шестым подъездом, попробовать разбить садик?